# REST API URL design Best practices

Tags: rest, api, url

I am developing a REST API for a system which has a lot of setting parameters. All these parameters should be able to change.  These parameters are grouped in categories and have unique names. The parameters have different measuring units and they are of different types (boolean, number or object with several properties). For example I have parameters "flow" and "threshold" which belong to category "process" and one parameter "name" which belongs to category "general". What is the usual way to define URLs? Is it:

```
/process/flow

/process/threshold

/general/name
```

Or is it better that each parameter has an unique number (id). And without using the categories the URL can be simply defined as follows:

```
/param/{id}
```

Answer (score 0):

> REST API URL design Best practices

REST doesn't care about URL design.  So long as the identifiers that you use conform to the production rules described by [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A), you can use any spelling you like.

```
/general/name
/param/12345
/3eaa7b95-c46b-4290-9614-546dc17c1f2d
```

Those are all *fine*.  From the perspective of a general purpose component (like a web browser, or a cache), the URI is *opaque* -- we never "parse" the URI to extract semantic information from it.

What that means is that the server can embed within the URI whatever information it needs to identify the resource - whether that be a human readable token, or a surrogate key, or a hash... it's all good.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!!! But what is the best practice for URI using human readable URIs or cryptical ids for identifying parameter settings? What would you do?